# Transfer I-485 basis from EB-1b (employer-based) to EB1-A (self petition)?

Tags: usa, immigration, residency, greencard, employment

My previous company filed EB-1b for me, and it is pending. But I was laid off two months ago (it is now pending more than 180 days and they didn't withdraw it- I was laid off before 180 days though). I have my EAD/AP now.

One option is to use AC21 to move to a similar job. But a lawyer told me one option for me is to file a new self-petition I-140 (EB1-A) and transfer the pending I-485 to the new one. I already re-scheduled my USCIS appointment, so I have to decide soon.

Which one is recommended? Pros/cons? If you know a good firm practicing that with reasonable fees, let me know.